# How do I load an FXML file from another project using JavaFX in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, fxml, scene

I have two projects: "Game" and "Game Library" - Game has a build path to the Game Library project. In Game Library, I have a method that switches the scene when Game requests it.

The scene switch method in Game Library project:

```
package gamelibrary;

public class SceneSwitcher{

    public Stage window;
    public Parent root;

    public void switchSceneFXML(String FXMLLocation) throws Exception{

        try{

            window = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();

        }catch(Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(FXMLLocation));

        window.setScene(new Scene(root));
        window.show();

    }
}
```

I call this method in Game project:

```
package game;

import gamelibrary.sceneSwitcher;

public class firstWindowController{

    public void buttonHandler(ActionEvent event){

        SceneSwitcher scene = new SceneSwitcher();

        if(event.getSource().equals(playButton){

            scene.switchScene("/game/SecondWindow.fxml");

        }

    }

}
```

So when I click the playButton in the FirstWindow.fxml, FirstWindowController in Game project will call the switchSceneFXML method in Game Library project.

I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.

at

```
root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(FXMLLocation));
```

at

```
scene.switchSceneFXML("/game/SecondWindow.fxml");
```

Is there something i'm missing? How can I make switchSceneFXML method know to look for the package and file in Game project and not Game Library project?

I am trying to make switchSceneFXML method reusable with other FXML files so that I dont have to copy and paste code alot and would prefer a way that will allow me to write once and reuse.

I have looked around alot for an answer but I havent been able to fully grasp the concept in other peoples situations. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is `"/companytycoon/LauncherGUI.fmxl"` (`fmxl` instead of `fxml`) a typo in the question, or in your code?

Comment: in `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(FXMLLocation))` you have to call `getClass()` on a class that is in this other Project:   `FXMLLoader.load(ClassInOtherProject.class.getResource(FXMLLocation))`

Comment: @James_D yes that was a typo. I corrected that.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I am trying to make the switchSceneFXML method reusable for more than just one FXML. Is there a way I can get the name of the class automatically?

Comment: you said you have two project, what is the packaging of it, is it jar?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle is probably correct that this is a class loader issue. If you wanted the `SceneSwitcher` to be independent of the other classes, you could make the `Class<?>` (or `ClassLoader`) a parameter to the `switchSceneFXML` method.

Comment: @Vishrant It's two different projects in an eclipse workspace. I added the Game Library project to the Game project buildpath. They are both project's, neither one is a jar.

Comment: @James_D Could you supply a step by step example for this?

Comment: @Chris Thats the way it is: separate Projects usually end up as separate Jars in the final distribution...

Comment: Well, testing this (just as two Eclipse projects; I didn't bundle as jars, which might introduce more issues), it worked just fine basically as-is. So I think you have an issue which is unrelated to the classes being in different projects (e.g. the path is wrong - FXML file is not in the `game` package - or the FXML file is not being deployed to the build folder, etc etc).

Comment: @Chris so when you will build the application they should be built as one jar and you should give absolute path of the FXML file you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make the switchSceneFXML method reusable for more than just on FXML. Is there a way I can get the name of the class automatically? – Chris

Then you should have the various classes load their FXML themselves. You could Do this by using the JVMs [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)

in gane lib:

```
interface FxmlController{
  boolean isPrividingScene(String nextSceneIdOrName);
  String getFXMLLocation();
}


public class SceneSwitcher{
    public Stage window;
    public Parent root;
   private static ServiceLoader<FxmlController> sceneControllers
     = ServiceLoader.load(FxmlController.class);
    public void switchSceneFXML(String nextSceneIdOrName) throws Exception{
        try{
            window = (Stage) node.getScene().getWindow();
            for(FxmlController controller : sceneControllers){
               if(controller.isPrividingScene(nextSceneIdOrName)){ // however you want to select the next scene...
                 FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
                 fxmlLoader.setController(controller);
                 root = fxmlLoader.load(controller.getClass().getResource(controller.getFXMLLocation()));
                 window.setScene(new Scene(root));
                 window.show();
               }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This way each FxmlController can (but does not need to) live in its own jar file having its own relative path to the FXML file.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot.

Comment: You have to add the Project containing the Controller and the FXML to the *runtime classpath* (in the *run configuration*) of the game-lib project for this to work.

Comment: Years later I am replying with yes in-fact, this did work (within the same project - not separate jars)  - but i patiently took a couple of months to figure it out by myself... It worked; I used most of the code provided by this answer but I didn't utilize ServiceLoader... (No idea why) The only issue that I truly had afterwards was when I switched the scene the Stage would be on another thread... probably rendering it a useless method. Now, I'm progressing and have decided to scrap JavaFX and integrate plain old Java Swing into my current project... FX, years may pass, but still in my heart.